# My report’s job has changed leading to more management involvement - now I am being accused of micromanagment

Tags: management, job-change

Our company has recently gone through a change of direction and my reports have had a change of job role that I am not sure they are happy with. I have tried to reassure them that this a learning curve and be supportive. Their previous role was target based and I did not need to ask how they were doing as the figures spoke for themselves, now they are taking on different task and I have to play a more active management role asking them how they are getting on. They are homeworkers, they are resistant to coming back to the office which our CEO has asked for on a two day a week basis. I am sending them emails with required tasks trying not to be to heavy handed and they are not responding this is new for all of us. I have now been accused of micromanagement and intimidation. There basis for this lies in their job description(the new one) saying they can work with minimal management guidance and they feel that me asking how they are getting on maybe once twice a week is too much. I am struggling in trying to fulfil the requirements of my job while trying to make sure I am not overbearing. They don't accept that there are some things I have to know to report to my manager. I feel in a real pickle any advice would be great.

Comment: "Accused" by whom? What actions have you taken so far, have you spoken to your manager?

Comment: Sorry should of explained it is my staff that have accused me, they have worked for my for 16 years but since the change in their job role this has come up. We have had a meeting with a senior team member who has tried to defuse the situation but I feel that this is not the end of it. I understand they are feeling the change but I have to fulfil my role to does this make sense

Comment: My manager is away for another fortnight

Comment: “I have now been accused of micromanagement and intimidation.” - If your requests are reasonable, and they are ignoring you, it’s time you take disciplinary actions. If you have or made it clear that ignoring reasonable requests from their management will not be tolerated and it’s still a problem, take the next step, that your authorized to make. Make it clear your job, is to manage them and understand, if they need assistance in doing their job. By blocking your ability to do your job, their actions, are causing you problems.

Comment: Thank you both very much that information really helps.

Comment: Do you have regular one-on-one meetings/calls with your direct reports? Having a regular schedule to give a business update or two to them, and give them the opportunity to ask questions that you might help with, can really help learn what works for each of you. One-on-ones can be just a few minutes, or go an hour if the topics that week warrant it. Once a week to once a month frequency is common.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your own manager how to handle this. Part of his job is to teach you how to manage.

Generally, if folks should know what they are supposed to be doing, pestering them with reminders *is* micromanaging.

Give them the assignments, let them work, do period progress meetings (I am personally very fond of the Scrum approach WHEN IT IS DONE RIGHT, meaning no more than two or three minutes per person per meeting and probably not every day), use a ticket/issue-tracking system to cooperatively record priorities and progress, and unless something *needs* to be communicated stay out of their way, respect that they're adults, and let them do their job.

***Addendum*** (thanks, @DarkCygnus)

Even twice a week *can be* intrusive and send a signal that you don't trust them to keep you informed... Unless , as I say, it is structured as something like a scrum meeting, an extremely brief all-hands clearly intended to keep *everyone* informed. And even scrum can be intrusive; I've seen the scrum process moved to bulletin board systems very successfully and I, at least, prefer that. (I read a lot faster than most people speak, and writing lets me organize my thoughts better and include examples and so on.)

The phrasing of an inquiry also matters a lot; a regularly scheduled "hey, is there anything you need or are stuck on, or anything I should know" is very different from an unscheduled  "stop what you are in the middle of and give me a full progress report, right now."

Comment: OP mentions: *"they feel that me asking how they are getting on maybe once twice a week is too much"* which tells us this is not every day, it's once or twice a week. The ticket system is a great suggestion, that way it will be clear to everybody the things to be done and OP will know exactly when are those things finished/in-progress/etc.

Comment: as to why mails can feel more annoying: They are a pull method and hit you unprepared and they can feel like more personal - it is much less personal if you have status meeting were visibly everyone gets to present their status and you see that others are sometimes behind too or need to argue their case. When it's all 1-1 it can feel that you are the only one with "problems" or (perceived) delays. And conversely if there is a meeting then it's a push method, you can prepare if you need to and you know exactly when it "hits you".

Comment: regarding the immediate impact: While typically email is less "pushy" than IM, some feel they need to answer directly if there is no proper attitude of "mail can wait a day".
Feel free to incorporate any of that if you agree.